# Import a query from one database to another

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to import a query from one database to another using the following syntax:

```
strDbFile = "P:\Cadworx P&ID Implementation\3 Piping\P&IDs Jesus Test\Testproject\myTest.mdb"
strSourceTableName = "qryComponents_Process_Lines_Report"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", strDbFile, acQuery, strSourceTableName, "Test", False
```

Yet when I do this, it gives me an error saying that the table or query was not found. What I find odd is that it does not have the name that I assigned it just before running the TransferDatabase command. See below.

[image: Error for Query name]

Comment: I'll guess that query is based on a table or another query named `Components-Process Lines` and the database where you're doing that `DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport` does not contain a table or query named `Components-Process Lines`.

Comment: @HansUp the source file has a table called 'Components-Process-Lines' and in fact there is not a table in the destination file with that name. So wouldn't that defeat the purpose of importing a query if I have to import the table from the source file?

Comment: I'm confused!  If you want the query to work, first 1.) import the table it requires or 2.) create a link which points to that table in the other database.  Then you could be OK when you import the query.

Comment: @HansJUp, just created the table making a link to the source database and it worked perfectly. You are the MVP.

Comment: @HansUp by the way, is there a shortcut to comment my code instead of having to press the space key 4 times for every single line?

Comment: Yes.  Select your code lines to highlight them, then press Ctrl+k.  Or after highlighting the code lines, click the `{}` button on the toolbar at the top of the textarea window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
strSourceTableName = "Components-Process Lines"                                                                   'Source Table
strLinkName = "Components-Process Lines"                                                                          'Final table name once link has been established

strConnect = "MS Access;PWD=" & strPassword & ";DATABASE=" & strDbFile

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set tdf = dbs.CreateTableDef

tdf.Connect = strConnect                                                                           'Establish link between databases
tdf.SourceTableName = strSourceTableName
tdf.Name = strLinkName
dbs.TableDefs.Append tdf

strSourceTableName = "qryComponents_Process_Lines_Report"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", strDbFile, acQuery,    strSourceTableName, "Test", False
```

All I had to do is create a link to the original table where the query in the source database is source query comes from (located in source database). Once this is done, the import process was successful.